# reading from a binary file in c++

Tags: c++, file, binary

In C++, when I try to read int value from a binary file it gives me 0z till infinity, I know I shouldn't read like this from a binary file. But I want to know why does it print 0z?

```
test.open("grade.dat", ios::in);
int num;
while (!test.eof())
{
    test >> num;
    cout << num << endl;
}
```

Comment: a couple of numbers: 3 2 1

Comment: Is this all your code? (BTW use `while (test >> num)` *not* `while (!test.eof())`)

Comment: I write in the file in the beginning and it outputs right using the classic test.read(). but whenever I try to read as an int this way it gives me this

Comment: For *binary* or untranslated input files, you need to OR in the `ios::binary` mode as in `ios::in | ios::binary` and use `std::istream.read`.

Comment: I know, and I mentioned that. I just need to know where do all these zeros come from. What does it actually read

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `ios::binary` is usually irrelevant for working on OS other than windows isn't it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: No, `ios::binary` is relevant.  If you use ios::binary, you don't need to worry about which platform you are running on.  There are many platforms out there besides Windows or Linux.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews _'There are many platforms out there besides Windows or Linux'_ Sure I know (and should!!). THX for clarifying.